# Difference between scanf("%s",name); and scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", name);

Tags: c

I have written RSA using GMP packages. While taking plain text I've taken it as string using `scanf("%s",name);`
 and then converted into gmp type. After running my program for 50 times,which was successfully executed, the scanf function haven't worked. So, I've read the input using `fgets (name, 100, stdin);` and `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", name);` and it worked well.

What is the difference between using these 2 type of scanf functions.

Comment: Use `fgets`, both those scans are unsafe: http://powerfield-software.com/?p=65

Comment: After using fgets I recommend sscanf to parse the data from fgets. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scanf("%s",name);
```

Will scan user input until it encounters a space,i.e, when you type `hi bye` , only `hi` will be stored in `name`.On the other hand,

```
scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", name);
```

Will scan until it encounters a `\n` or an enter key. The `%*c` tells `scanf` to scan a character and discard it. In your case,`%*c` discards the `\n` character which is present in the `stdin` as you pressed it after entering the string.

Comment: The `%*c` is supposed to discard the newline, so that `name` contains the whole line and removes the newline from the buffer. However this doesn't work if the line was empty (i.e. the first character in the buffer was a newline), so the code should really be `scanf("%[^\n]", name); scanf("%*c");`

Comment: 1) `"%s"` first consume leading white-space.  `"%[^\n]%*c"` does not. 2) return values are different.